# Error with instantiating a store explicitly in view

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have view like this:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.CustomersList', {
    extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

    store: Ext.create('MyApp.store.Customers'),

    columns: [
        {
            width: 150,
            dataIndex: 'customerName',
            text: 'CustomerName'
        },
        {
            width: 200,
            dataIndex: 'customerNumber',
            flex: 1,
            text: 'CustomerNumber'
        }
    ]
});
```

I instantiate a store explicitly, but when I load this view in Viewport, I find an error like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got function constructor() {
        // Opera has some problems returning from a constructor when Dragonfly isn't running. The || null seems to
        // be sufficient to stop it misbehaving. Known to be required against 10.53, 11.51 and 11.61.
        return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments) || null;
    } 

Uncaught TypeError: Expecting a function in instanceof check, but got function constructor() {
        // Opera has some problems returning from a constructor when Dragonfly isn't running. The || null seems to
        // be sufficient to stop it misbehaving. Known to be required against 10.53, 11.51 and 11.61.
        return this.constructor.apply(this, arguments) || null;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Ext.define('MyApp.view.CustomersList', {
      extend: 'Ext.grid.Panel',

      initComponent: function(){
      this.store = Ext.create('MyApp.store.Customers');

      this.columns = [
      {
        width: 150,
        dataIndex: 'customerName',
        text: 'CustomerName'
      },
      {
        width: 200,
        dataIndex: 'customerNumber',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'CustomerNumber'
      }]
    this.callParent();
   }
   });
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: thanks for your help, I appreciate it. The class is load well, without error. But when I invoke {store}.load() method from controller, the store does not load the data, so the grid is blank. What I do to solve this problem is I add 'MyApp.store.Customers' in requires config in app.js.

Comment: Glad it helped!! I would recommend to create the store in a separate file outside the view. You can provide some more details or code sample which would help in identifying the problem.